# How to solve "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im new in programming. I´ve been working with react js and when a tried to deploy (i think) my portfolio it came up this error on the console:
"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()"
It came from my svgs, pngs and a pdf in src/assets folder.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJVAz.png)

My repository: https://github.com/MaximilianoLeonel23/portafolio

Any help will be great, thanks

I tried to change the relative path but I don´t know what to put. Also I tried to move the assets to public folder and build but it didn´t work too

Comment: Please add the relevant piece of code in the question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please see [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/328193)  Relevant code needs to be included in the question to produce a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem, as well as information about the problem itself and what debugging you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: A 404 error means your application cant find the images/svg's its looking for. You need to look into how your app is serving them or looking for them.

Comment: [Some research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/4665) is expected before asking a question. What has your research into 404 errors shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, your page/app is unable to locate those files, hence the 404 error.

In your repository, I see that you have places the 'assets' folder under 'src'.

You are using vitejs which copies all static assets under 'public' to the build folder, so move the 'assets' folder and its content under 'public'. Also, change path references to '/assets/icons/<file_name.extension>'. Example: 'src\assets\icons\whatsapp.svg' to be changed to '/assets/icons/whatsapp.svg'

Hope this helps.

Comment: I was trying to solve it and at the end the problem was that i didn´t import the svg from assets. Im stuck in little thing like this, but thanks for the advice, i didn´t notice that i could do that too.